# ValueError: not a valid sha256_crypt hash

Tags: python, authentication, flask, sha256, flask-login

I am working on this application and I have set up a registration and login page.
Everything works perfectly fine, the only issue is with the password validation. I am using SHA256 and every time I try logging I get this error : `ValueError: not a valid sha256_crypt hash` here is a piece of def register

```html
def register():
    if request.method=="POST":
        name = request.form.get("name")
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirm = request.form.get("confirm")
        secure_password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(password))
```

and here is a login

```html
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
      
        usernamedata = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username", {"username":username}).fetchone()
        passwordata = db.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username", {"username":username}).fetchone()

        if usernamedata is None:
            flash("No username", "danger")
            return render_template("/login.html")
        else:
              for passwor_data in passwordata:
                if sha256_crypt.verify(password,passwor_data):
                    flash("You are now logged in","success")
                    return redirect("/index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over each character of the hash in `for passwor_data in passwordata:`, so it throws this error, complaining that the second argument is not a valid sha256 hash.

It should be something like :

```
if sha256_crypt.verify(password, passwordata):
    flash("You are now logged in","success")
    return redirect("/index.html")
```

- password is the clear text password received from user input
- passwordata is sha256 hash

Short example :

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

password = "test"
passwordata = sha256_crypt.encrypt(password)

if sha256_crypt.verify(password, passwordata):
    print("OK")
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested and not i am getting this error: TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy

Comment: @BelloCooper you need to convert it to string then

Comment: i am trying to to it like this :if sha256_crypt.verify(password, passwordata(str)):. its now throwing in this error TypeError: 'RowProxy' object is not callable

Comment: I don't know this `passwordata(str)` ?

Comment: trying to convert the hash back to string. i thought thats the way its done. let me know if its not right

Comment: @BelloCooper maybe passwordata[0] I don't know sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy